# Use DCM for generate clock of 78 mhz from 100 mhz clock

Tags: vhdl, clock, fpga, xilinx

I have a clock of 100 mhz. I want to use DCM to create a clock of 78 mhz.

I think I should use two DCM, where the output of first DCM goes into the second DCM but I don't know if this will work.

Best Regards

Comment: Can you elaborate on your idea of using 2 DCMs? How exactly will it work? Have you tried anything?

Comment: i think use the 100 mhz for input in first dcmm, the output of first dcm i use for input of second dcm

Comment: Cascading DCMs is not a great idea, you have to be careful how the jitter adds up.  And that the output frequency is achieveable - if you plan to multiply up to 3900MHz you'll be disappointed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What device are you targeting?  On a Spartan-6 the DCM_CLKGEN allows a multiplier of 39 and a divider of 50, which gets you your 78MHz.

Comment: i use a Spartan-3 and i resolve it, in first dcm i obtain 3900 mhz and later i devide for 50, 3900/50 =78

thx for all

Comment: Have you run this in real silicon, or just simulation?  As I've said before, it seems unlikely you'll really get 3900MHz out of a part which tops out at a few hundred MHz (in terms of achievable logic clock)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a DCM directly you can investigate using a Direct Digital Frequency Synthesizer (DDFS). It amounts to an accumulator that is incremented by a constant count value. You can control the precision by the size of the accumulator.

It is helpful if there is as much disparity between the accumulator clock and the generated frequency as possible. Consider using a DCM to scale the 100MHz up to the highest speed you can run a counter of the necessary width and still meet timing for your target device. There will be some jitter equal to one period of whatever clock is driving the accumulator but the average frequency can be made very close to 78 MHz.

```
accum_freq = 100 MHz * DCM_MULTIPLIER
accum_size = ceil(log2(accum_freq / (78 MHz * tolerance)))
increment = 78 MHz / accum_freq * 2**accum_size

accum = accum + increment
```

You then tap off the MSB of the accumulator to get your synthesized 78 MHz clock.

You can either manually compute these constants for use as magic numbers or do the arithmetic natively in VHDL to define the size and increment as machine computed constants. By reducing the tolerance you will increase the required size of the accumulator. Start off with 0.01% (0.0001) and see if it is satisfactory.

Comment: You're generating your own clock in FPGA fabric, and using that generated clock to drive other FPGA resources.  This is in general a really bad idea, and should only be done if you have no other options left.  The problem is the tools have a very hard time with this type of situation.  Performing timing analysis on this might give invalid results.  Also your jitter is going to be very high.

Comment: No it isn't being used as a clock for internal resources unless you connect it that way. A DDFS output stays synchronous to the domain it is generated from and you can use it as a clock enable in the data path. Yes the jitter will be high and this technique is more suited to generating low frequency timing (Baud generator for instance) but the question didn't put any limit on jitter.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your multiplier to 7 and your divider to 9 you'll be able to get to 77.77 MHz. Will that work for you?

Comment: i want 78 mhz, 77.77 is different

Comment: Yes, well good luck to you then. Xilinx specifically recommends not chaining DCMs because it causes high jitter.

Comment: i resolve it, in first dcm i obtain 3900 mhz and later i devide for 50, 3900/50 =78